# open() a file and write at the end

Tags: c, shell, unix, stdout, stdin

I currently working on a C shell program with some `pipe()` and redirection.

I redirect with `dup2()` *stdout* and *stderr* (1 & 2).

When i open a file with `int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);` with a loop to print `"---------\n"` to separe everything sometime it's appear, sometime it don't and sometimes it delete what was write before .

Did someone have a explanation ?

I would like every new text arrive at the end of what was write before in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `O_APPEND` flag is for. When a file can get updated from another process at any time, you need `O_APPEND` to make sure your `write` will always be at the end.